# Whitelisting of Patterns in a Set of Patterns with controlled Multi Occurance in Regex

Tags: regex, string

I want the following examples to return match

- I like **foobar.com**
- I like google.com and **foobar.com**
- I like **foobar.com** and google.com
- I like foobargoogle.com and google**foobar.com**
- I like yahoo.com and **foobar.com**
- I like **foobar.com** and yahoo.com
- I like foobaryahoo.com and yahoo**foobar.com**

I don't want the following examples to return match

- I like **yahoo.com**
- I like foobar**yahoo.com**
- I like **google.com**
- I like foobar**google.com**
- I like **google.com** and **yahoo.com**
- I like foobar**google.com** and foobar**yahoo.com**

Note - It's not an equal match but a contain match

I tried the following Regex Pattern:

```
(?!(^.*((google)|(yahoo))\.com.*$))(^.*\w+\.com.*$)
```

but as soon as either "google.com" or "yahoo.com" occured, it terminated with no match even if "foobar.com" occured before it.

eg. I like foobar.com but not google.com

Basically, I want it to ignore "google.com" and "yahoo.com" anywhere in the string and detect any other type: "\w+.com".

Note:

- **google.com** and **yahoo.com** are just examples. So, it should ignore match set of any string length of alphanumeric characters
- ignore case and whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this through the PCRE verb [(*SKIP)(*F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) .

```
(?:google|yahoo)(?:\.com)?(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!google|yahoo)\w)+\.com
^                                    ^                           ^
|------Part you don't want-----------|------------Part you want--|
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nN2yU4/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?:google|yahoo)(?:\.com)?` matches abruptly `google` or `yahoo` strings with a following optional `.com`.  See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/nN2yU4/2).
- `(?:google|yahoo)(?:\.com)?(*SKIP)(*F)|` And the following PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` would cause the previous match to fail. And the following `|` OR will match all the boundaries which isn't followed by `google` or `yahoo` strings. See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/nN2yU4/3)
- `(?:(?!google|yahoo)\w)+\.com` Now the regex engine would consider the matched boundaries  as starting point, it abruptly matches one or more word characters but not of `google` or `yahoo`.
- `\.com` Helps to match only the strings which ends with `.com`

Answer (score 1):

No need to be so complicated.
This finds exactly what you highlighted in the *want* lines.

```
 # (?:\w(?<!google)(?<!yahoo))+\.com

 (?:
      \w                # Match words but not google or yahoo behind
      (?<! google )
      (?<! yahoo )
 )+
 \. com
```